# Perl module import error

Tags: mongodb, perl, perl-module

I have installed MongoDB perl module.

I got a simple perl script (below):

```
 use MongoDB ();
 print "OK!\n";
```

When I compile this perl script, I get the following errors:

```
"all" is not exported by the List::Util module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/OO.pm 
line 9
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/OO.pm 
line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/Coercion.pm 
line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
/usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/Coercion.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/Declare.pm 
line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
/usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/Declare.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Types.pm 
line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Types.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Duration.pm 
line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Duration.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 
14.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/MongoDB/BSON.pm line 
35.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/MongoDB/BSON.pm 
line 35.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/MongoDB.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/MongoDB.pm line 
32.
Compilation failed in require at script.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.pl line 2.
```

In **/usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/OO.pm** line 9, the following use statement is there.

```
use List::Util qw( all );
```

I believe the above line is the reason for all the errors because they seem to be nested from this file.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: What does `perl -MList::Util -E 'say $List::Util::VERSION'` say? By looking at the [Changes](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Scalar-List-Utils) log, `all()` was introduced in version `1.33`, so you need that version or higher.

Comment: If you have a version less than that, and you find that upgrading `List::Util` fixes it, I will create a pull request that sets a minimum version for `MongoDB`.

Comment: @stevieb perl -MList::Util -E 'say $List::Util::VERSION' says 1.21 so do I have to upgrade my version to 1.33 or higher?

Comment: Yes you do. I'm just doing a test on perl 5.10.1 now to confirm this. After I'm done, and if it works, I'll post it as an answer and create a PR for `MongoDB` that'll fix the issue.

Comment: So, perl 5.10.1 is bundled with `List::Util` version `1.21`, but when I `cpanm MongoDB` to install it, something along the way upgraded my `List::Util` to `1.48` and it all works fine without making any other changes. How did you install the distribution?

Comment: I installed MongoDB perl module manually with make and make install statements. I have perl 5.10.1

Comment: Ahhh. So in that case, you have to manually install all prerequisites yourself.

Comment: That's a bug in Specio since it's using List::Util::all and not declaring a high enough prerequisite for List::Util.

Answer (score -1):

There might be a module that is calling the exported routine qw( all ) recursively.

The following exported method is called by /usr/local/share/perl5/Specio/OO.pm line 9:

```
use List::Util qw( all );
```

This method may also be called by the module being used in script.pl in line 2.

```
Compilation failed in require at script.pl line 2.
```

Instead use require in a code block instead of use List::Util qw( all ); in the given module in script.pl line 2 only where it is required.

This may fix the issue that you are facing.